# ActionListeners in Java

Tags: java

Ok so I have two classes in which they are not really associated with each other.
One is the graphic the other in inputs(by terminal using scanners). I want to replace the scanners with a JTextField but I am having a hard time doing so..

Im a bit lost here....

Here is class GUI

```
//Constructor to create the UI components
 public UnoGraphics() {

  //JButtons---------------------------- 
  viewCards = new JButton("Move Card"); 
  input = new JTextField(5);

  //Creates a canvas and set the properties 
  canvas = new DrawCanvas();
  canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH,CANVAS_HEIGHT));
  this.setContentPane(canvas);
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


//This is How I was thinking of implementing my input------------HERE---------------->
  input.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             inputText = input.getText();
         }});//End ActionListener()

  this.pack();
  this.setTitle("Uno!");
  this.setVisible(true);
 }//End Constructor

 //Custom drawing canvas (designed as inner class). This is were we draw/change the cards
  class DrawCanvas extends JPanel {
   // Custom drawing codes--------------
    @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

      //Set the background to black
      super.paintComponent(g);
      setBackground(Color.black);
     //cards being drawn-------------------
     //buttons and text fields
     add(viewCards);
     add(input);
   }//End PaintComponent()
  }//End DrawCavas()
 }//End Program
```

Class Two Inputs with scanners:

```
  public class CommandLinePlayer extends Player 
  {


//private String inputText;
// constructor
public CommandLinePlayer(String aname) 
{
    //super aname is from the super class player;
    super(aname);

}


    // command line player can also say uno.  This uses scanner(reads user in puts from keyboard) and the response should be typed in
    public boolean sayUno()
    {
        System.out.println("Would you like to say uno?  Yes or No");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String yes = scan.next();
        // returns response 
        //returns yes if the user types yes and ignores the case
        return yes.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes");
    }

    //this method is the choose card of type int takes int one argument of type Card
    // command line version (normal player on command line)
    //this method takes in the card from your hand and "sends" it to the controller
    protected int chooseCard(Card topCard)
    {
        // display hand
        System.out.println("\nHere is the topCard: " + topCard);

        System.out.println("Your hand has:");

        // loops through the players(commandlineplayer) hand and prints out the players cards.  Index could start at 0, but 1 would be the first card
        for(int index = 0; index < numOfCards; index ++)
        {
            System.out.println("Card # " + index + ": " + hand[index]);

        }
        // choose Card prompts the player to match, or pick a card based on the index, and then press enter.
        // if a card does not match the topcard, a key corresponding to any card can be pressed.  This would automatically add a
        // card to a players hand.
        System.out.println("Play a card #. If you don't have a card to play, choose any card # to draw.");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        return num;

    }


    // this is the choose color method for the command line player but only if it is a wild card does this method takes place
    // command line player can choose a cards color based on the options displayed on the screen.(System.out.println...statements)  
    public Card.Color chooseColor()
    {
        // choose a color using scanner
        Scanner scanin = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Choose a color by pressing a number corresponding to your choice:");

        System.out.println("Your options are 1.Red 2.Green 3.Yellow 4. Blue");

        // the switch corresponds a number (color) to the cases, and returns a chosen card.  
        int color = 0;
        color = scanin.nextInt();
        switch (color) 
        {
            case 1: System.out.println("The color you chose is: Red");
                    return Card.Color.Red;
            case 2: System.out.println("The color you chose is: Green");
                    return Card.Color.Green;
            case 3: System.out.println("The color you chose is: Yellow");
                    return Card.Color.Yellow;
            case 4: System.out.println("The color you chose is: Blue");
                    return Card.Color.Blue;
            default: System.out.println("NONE");
        }

           return Card.Color.None;          
    }

    public class inputListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            //I Was Thinking something like this-----------HERE-----
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: could you narrow down your problem? What are you having a hard time with?

Comment: Replacing the scanners with an JTextField(input)and adding it to my GUI(UnoGraphics()).

Comment: what are "scanners"? Text input from a OCR after digitalizing a piece of paper?

Comment: Sorry Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: Scanners read in text from an InputStream, e.g. stdin, files, and sockets.

Comment: this smells like homework. Would you mind adding the 'homework' tag to it?

Comment: So, if I got it right you want to display a GUI to a player who is on turn and wait for input. Input comes from a JTextField and a JButton. When the button is pressed or the JTextField receives the 'ENTER' Key you want to submit the form and parse the input, right?

Comment: Its not homeWork Its a side project im doing to get more familiar with GUI. I started using the Scanner class just test out my code (bad Idea) Now I just want to use text field and transfer that data to CommandLinePlayer(). also school semester is over it break

Comment: Correct Angelo, as of now CommandLinePlayer() does not wait for a player input it just takes the first input and plays that same input through the whole game.

Comment: @Henry I don't know where you live, but over here school / university is on. Remember this is an international server, your local situations are not known (nor cared about) by other users. Also homework can be something that has to be done over the breaks. Anyway: did the description of mine two posts above apply?

Comment: yes it does. on some previous comments I explain my situation a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the relevant chunks of code you need, you should be able to integrate them into your code yourself.

```
public class Controller {
    public void startMethod() {
        final UIClass myUI = new UIClass();
        myUI.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                handleUIInformation(myUI);
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleUIInformation(UIClass myUI) {
        String textval = myUI.textField.getText();
        // here you do whatever you want with the text
    }
}

public class UIClass {
    JButton button;
    JTextField textField;
    public UIClass() {
        button = new JButton();
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    button.doClick();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener al) {
        button.addActionListener(al);
    }
}
```

Comment: i got it thanks for your help, Im new to GUIs and want to learn more about them. Thank you once more

Comment: with ActionListener dont we have to use .actionPerformed(ActionEvent)?

Comment: I get an error Here myUI.addActionListener() it says i must use actionPerformed(actionEvent)